# Creating DateTime from two FormCollection data strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

In my `FormCollection` data I have two fields I need to combined into a `DateTime` filed. The Date is contained in `SlectedStartDay` in the format of `dd/MM/yyyy 12:00:00 AM` (the time never changes just the date) and the time is contained in `StartTime` in the format of `h:mm:ss tt`. I need to combine the two into a single `DateTime` variable but can not figure out how to do it since I am working form a `FormCollection`.

I have tried both `DateTime.Parse` as well as `Convert.ToDateTime` but each gives me the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". What is the right way to do this conversion?

```
private string AddTimesheet(FormCollection postData)
{
    var startDates = postData["SelectedStartDay"].Split(',');
    var startDateTime = DateTime.Parse(startDates[0] + postData["StartTime"]);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: couple of cheap and dirty ways to do it.  One is to get the first date's string format for just the date, combine it with the time and create a new datetime with that string.  You could also add the second time to the first datetime and get the same result.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Not sure what your suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a space between the StartDate and StartTime Value to make it as a valid Datetime,Think it will solve your problem

```
var startDates = postData["SelectedStartDay"].Split(',')[0].Split(' ')
var startDateTime = DateTime.Parse(startDates[0]+" "+ postData["StartTime"]);
```

Comment: @Kirsh to what? When the data comes in it is two different dates separated by a comma so I have to split it.

Comment: you need to have just the datepart in Startdate,now you are having both date and time part which is causing the Exception.Try to change the line like this to avoid the exception var startDates = postData["SelectedStartDay"].Split(',')[0].Split(' ')

Comment: if issue persist try to assign this value to a string to check whether gives a valid datetime.       String s= startDates[0]+" "+ postData["StartTime"]